# Different Text sizes within button

Tags: html

I'd like to display the text in parenthesis smaller than the rest of the button text.

```
<input type="button" value="Bigger Text (Smaller Text)"/>
```

Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using button type="button" instead of input type="button". So inside you can define a different style for smaller text.

```css
.btn {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.btn .small {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn">
  Bigger Text (<span class="small">Smaller Text</span>)
</button>
```

Comment: thank you, the issue is that the original button is from type="submit". So I guess I have to use the ".on('submit', ...)" function and remove the "action" from the form, right?

Comment: You can just use button type="submit" instead of suggested by me button type="button". So you would not need to remove action from the form and adding any javascript.